# Pass variable into a running node.js program

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, socket.io

I have an process which is running on my server in the background. The object is exported like this

```
module.exports = new Application()
```

because I only want one instance of the object to ever exist.

I then have a separate process which tries to call a prototyped function `process` of `Application`. It looks something like this

```
var app = require('./Application.js');

app.process(process.argv[2]);
```

and say the file is called `process.js`. I'll then call `node process.js thing_to_pass`

The trouble is, every time I do this is it re-instantiates `application` which leads to behavior I am not looking for.

How can I get around this? I was thinking of using `socket.io` to communicate between the two processes but this seems hackish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to go down the road you are trying to go down.  Because you have two different processes, you are going to make two different instances of `Application`.  Sending messages from one process to another via `socket.io` isn't that hackish imo, definitely something to consider.

You could also consider using `child_process` and sending messages with `kill` http://nodejs.org/api/process.html

Comment: Why is it declaring a new instance of application? why isn't it just pulling in the one that already exists?

Comment: Because you are using two different processes, they are completely independent.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux, I would suggest to use UNIX-domain sockets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a running process to receive new data, it has to listen for that data in some way. Whether you set up an HTTP server and accept and process requests with new data, or socket.io, or you wait for info from the command line, watch a file for changes, or what have you.

If you start up a whole separate process, it will be logically segregated in every way from the currently running process, and thank goodness or else completely separate apps could mess with each other in unintended ways.